# 417 Missing Token after server update

Tags: angularjs, angular, iis, cookies, server

I have some problems with my server that runs Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and Umbraco (Angular) XSFR Cookies and IIS 7.5.

I saw tons of 417 Missing token topics here in StackOverflow and in Our Umbraco but I can't understand what is going on.

After login, the backend returns these 417 missing tokens that disappear on refresh.

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEz3G.jpg)

I think that is not a problem related to the application but is related to the server. In fact, it started after Updates on all my sites.

Is the server changing the HTTP Headers? 
There is some hidden proxy that is doing this? (i did netsh and winhttp to see the active proxies, and the list is empty)
There is some other feature in Windows Server that causes these troubles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is related to a Microsoft update (KB4014514) in 2008 R2 Stardard Edition and Umbraco 7.2.x.